# Wrote my code to look for a mode but gives me the largest number

Tags: c, mode

I'm trying to find the mode of an sorted array, so I wrote the following code; However, it gives me the largest number in that array.

Can anyone help me out?

```
typedef struct mode {
  int self;
  int size;
} mode;

mode findmode(int *arr, int size) {
  mode x;
  int i = 0;
  int count = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i > 1 && i < size) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) ++count;
      if (arr[i] != arr[i - 1]) {
        x.size = count;
        x.self = arr[i - 1];
        count = 0;
        ++count;
      }
      if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
        if (count > x.size) x.size = count;
        x.self = arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Your second-last `if` accesses one past the last element of the array, and should the two statements after the last `if` be in `{}`?

Comment: I include them in one {}, but it still doesn't work the way I want

Comment: Use a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program.

Comment: You can use `else` instead of repeating the test with `!=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code using `if` and `else` combo to count the number of occurrences of a given number or `else` start over by setting the counter to one. In the last if you can check whether or not the current occurrence count is bigger than the one we've stored before and swap the current mode and size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mode
{
  int self;
  int size;
} mode;

mode findmode(int *arr, int size) 
{
  mode x;
  x.self = arr[0];
  x.size = 1;
  int i;
  int count = 1;
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) 
  {
      if(arr[i - 1] == arr[i])
      {
          count++;
      }
      else
      {
          count = 1;
      }
      if(count >= x.size)
      {
          x.self = arr[i];
          x.size = count;
      }
  }
  return x;
}

int main()
{
   int  arr[20] = {1,1,1,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8};
   mode m = findmode(arr, 20);

   printf("The mode is %d with a occurrence count of %d\n", m.self, m.size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also figured that out by my self. Thank you so much guys for helping me tho.
here is my new code.

```
mode findmode(int *arr,int size)
{
mode x;
int i=0;
int count=1;
x.size=0;
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
    if(i>0)
    {
        if(arr[i]==arr[i-1])
        {
            ++count;


        }

        if (arr[i]!=arr[i-1])
        {
            if(count>x.size)
            {x.size=count;
            x.self=arr[i-1];}   
            count= 0;
            ++count;



        }
    }

    }
    return x;
}
```